# Table sorting based on the number of occurrences of a particular item

Tags: sql, postgresql, multiple-columns

Here is a example table with 2 columns.

```
 id | name
------------
  1 | hello  
  2 | hello  
  3 | hello  
  4 | hello  
  5 | world  
  6 | world  
  7 | sam  
  8 | sam  
  9 | sam  
 10 | ball  
 11 | ball  
 12 | bat  
 13 | bat  
 14 | bat  
 15 | bat  
 16 | bat
```

In the above table here is the occurrence count

```
hello  - 4  
world  - 2  
sam    - 3  
ball   - 2  
bat    - 5
```

How to write  a query in psql, such that the output will be sorted from max occurrence of a particular name to min ? i.e like this

```
bat  
bat  
bat  
bat  
bat  
hello  
hello  
hello  
hello  
sam  
sam  
sam  
ball  
ball  
world  
world
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a temporary table to get counts for all the names, and then `JOIN` that to the original table for sorting:

```
SELECT yt.id, yt.name
FROM your_table yt INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS the_count, name
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY name
) t
ON your_table.name = t.name
ORDER BY t.the_count DESC, your_table.name DESC
```

Comment: You probably need to add `, your_table.name` to sorting to add some stability and an alias for the `name` column in `SELECT` clause.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, you are correct, and the OP implied that it wanted this.

Comment: thanks Tim for the reply. It works for first time. Then I add another entry for "sam" to make its count 4, and execute the query. The results go a bit crazy. Can you please try the same in your setup. I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: @user1416065 "crazy" is not the best technical issue explanation.

Comment: @user1416065 This sounds like a problem with your Postgres client, and is not relevant to the OP.  You can update your question with the "crazy" results, but I would advise against that.

Comment: in the output once I add another entry of "sam" to make its count 4, the output shows first 5 "bat", then one "sam", then 4"hello", then 4 "sam" and so on.

Comment: How are you "adding an entry" in Postgres?  It looks like your data is stale.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution using window function:

```
select name from table_name order by count(1) over (partition by name) desc, name;
```

This will avoid scanning `table_name` twice as in Tim's solution and may perform better in case of big `table_name` size.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with a temporal table, if the original table is named sorting:

```
create temp table counted as select name, count(name) from sorting group by name;

select sorting.name from sorting, counted where sorting.name = counted.name order by count desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT count( ID ) cnt, NAME
FROM table_name
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY count( ID ) DESC;
```